# Definition of a left-invariant vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In DoCarmo’s Riemannian Geometry book, a smooth vector field $X$ on a Lie group $G$ is called left invariant if $d(L_x)_yX=X$ for all $x,y\in G$.

The left side maps each $y\in G$ to the tangent space $T_{xy}G$ while the right side maps each $y$ to $T_yG$. So in what sense are they equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $X$ a vector field.  For $g\in G$, let $L_g:G\to G$ denote left-multiplication, i.e., $L_g(p)=gp$.  Then we say that $X$ is left-invariant if
$$(L_g)_*X=X.$$
Note that the pushforward makes sense on vector fields since $L_g$ is a diffeomorphism.  Making this explicit at a point, say at $p\in G$ yields
$$X_{L_g(p)}=((L_g)_*X)_p$$
(this is saying $X$ is $L_g$-related with itself).  Or rewritten, we have that
$$X_{gp}=d(L_g)_p(X_p).$$

Comment: Thanks, I should use such pushforwards to make sense of such expressions