# Small question regarding left invariant vectorfields

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, vector-fields

Usually, one writes out the left invariance of vector fields $X$ on a Lie group $G$ as $$(L_x)_*X=X$$for every $x$.

However, I have trouble understanding this equality, since both sides does not map to the same domain. Evaluating the right hand side in $y$ gives an element in $T_yG$. Evaluating the left hand side in $y$ yields an element in $T_{xy}G$. Is there some canonical identification between $T_{xy}G$ and $T_yG$ going on, or did I make a mistake somewhere? Or, are we actually evaluating the right hand side in $xy$ instead of $y$?

Thank you. My apologies if this is duplicate.

I already found this one: [Definition of a left-invariant vector field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3004064/definition-of-a-left-invariant-vector-field), 
but I do not fully understand the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your instinct to keep track of the base point of a vector is a good one. Doing so here sheds a little light on the situation:

Each map $L_x : G \to G$, $x \in G$ is a diffeomorphism, and for any vector field $X$, $(L_x)_* X$ conveniently denotes the vector field whose value at $y \in G$ is $$((L_x)_* X)_y = ((L_x)_*)_{x^{-1} y} X_{x^{-1} y} .$$ To say that $X$ is left-invariant is just to say that this coincides with $X_y$ for all $x$. (This notation is obviously a little unwieldy, and the lower-star notation for the pushforward discourages writing down the base point explicitly, so I would prefer to write this as $$T_{x^{-1} y} L_x \cdot X_{x^{-1} y} ,$$ where $T_{x^{-1} y} L_x : T_{x^{-1} y} G \to T_y G$ is the differential of $L_x$ at $x^{-1} y$.) In practice we often take $y = x$ and so write the left-invariance condition as $$L_x \cdot X_e = X_x$$ (for all $x \in G$). (I encourage you to convince yourself that the two given conditions really are equivalent.)

More generally, we can talk about the pushforward of a vector field $Y \in \Gamma(TM)$ along a diffeomorphism $\phi : M \to N$, namely, $T\phi \cdot Y$, where
$$(T \phi \cdot Y)_q = T_{\phi^{-1}(q)} \phi\cdot Y_{\phi^{-1}(q)} .$$
One cannot, however, push forward a vector field by an arbitrary smooth map.

Comment: What exactly does the $((L_x)_*)_{x^-1y}$ notation mean? I see that when using this $T_{x^-1y}L_x\cdot X_{x^{-1}y}$, we end up with a vector in $T_yG$. However, I can still not understand why one thinks of this $T_{x^-1y}L_x\cdot X_{x^{-1}y}$ as being related to $(L_x)_*X=X$. There is nothing in this equations which tells us we have to consider the differential in the point $x^{-1}y$, is there?

Comment: If $f : M \to N$ is a smooth function, as you know we can denote the pushforward as $f_*$. If we want to emphasize the base point, we can write $(f_*)_p$. Of course, if instead of $f$ we have a function denoted with a subscript, say, $f_a$, we're forced to write $((f_a)_\ast)_p$ or similar. So, $((L_x)_\ast)_{x^{-1} y}$ is just the pushforward map (differential) $T_{x^{-1} y} G \to T_y G$ of $L_x$ at the point $x^{-1} y$.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of the left multiplication map, $L_g(x)=gx$ gives an isomorphism of the tangent spaces.  See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/720474/403337).

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a vector field on $G$. For each $g\in G,$ the map $g\mapsto xg$ is a diffeomorphism of $G$ so the pushforward $(L_x)_*:T_gG\to T_{xg}G$ is well-defined.

Now, $(L_x)_*$ maps vectors in $T_gG$ to vectors in $T_{xg}G$. And so if $X$ is a vector field on $G$, then $(L_x)_*X_g$ is $some$ vector $v_{xg}\in T_{xg}G$.

$\textit{If}\ $  it turns out that $v_{xg}=X_{xg}$ for every $g\in G,$  we say that $X$ is left-invariant. Of course, this does not say that there are any such fields, but this is another matter.

Comment: $x$ is fixed here. The map is $g\mapsto Lg=xg$, right? The typo was in the second sentence, which I fixed. Thanks--

Comment: Yes, I see. I will correct.

Comment: So, if I understand it correctly, we evaluate the left hand side of the $(L_x)_*X=X$ relation in $y$, and the right hand side in $xy$.

Comment: Yes, if $L_x$ is left invariant, then $(L_x)_*$ maps $T_gG$ to $T_{xg}G: X_g\mapsto X_{xg}$